# In UI-Router how to set component property to child state parameter value

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have these two route definitions, product list and product detail:

```
{
  name: "product",
  url: "/product",
  component: ProductListComponent,
  resolve: [
    {
      token: "Products",
      deps: [ApiService],
      resolveFn: (api: ApiService) => api.getProducts().toPromise()
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: "product.detail",
  url: "/:productcode",
  component: ProductDetailComponent,
  resolve: [
    {
      token: "Product",
      deps: [Transition, ApiService],
      resolveFn: (transition: Transition, api: ApiService) => 
        api.getProduct(transition.params().productcode).toPromise()
    }
  ]
}
```

Inside the product list component I have a set of radio buttons to indicate which product is selected, while the ui-view displays the product detail component:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of Products" class="radio">
    <label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="SelectedProduct" 
            [value]="product" 
            (change)="RefreshDetail()" 
            name="selectedProduct" 
            type="radio"> 
            {{product.Name}} {{product.Code}}
    </label>
</div>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

When the user clicks the radio button, the URL, the product detail component, and the radio button are synchronized correctly.

But when the user goes directly to a certain product URL, the URL and product detail component display the correct product, but the radio button doesn't. What I mean by going directly to a certain product URL is the user inputs the URL to the browser address bar and press enter.

I tried to get the value of `:productcode` from the Transition object in ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let prodcode = this.transition.params().productcode;
    this.SelectedProduct = !!prodcode
        ? this.Products.find(product => product.Code == prodcode)
        : null;
}
```

It works for browser refresh, the right product is selected in the radio button. But doesn't work on browser back button, no radio buttons are selected. (maybe because this parent state is not reinitialized?)

Anyway I'm not sure that this is the idiomatic way to get the parameter values of a child state.

What is the proper way to set component property value based on child state parameter value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UI-Router Rx extensions](https://github.com/ui-router/rx) provide a stream of transitions and parameters.  In your component, subscribe to the param stream and update the SelectedProduct

```
@Component({})
class {
  private sub;
  constructor(router: UIRouter) {
    this.sub = router.globals.params$.subscribe(params => {
      this.SelectedProduct = params.productcode;
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The Rx Extensions are already included in `@uirouter/angular`

Comment: for typescript to compile I needed `declare module '@uirouter/core' {
    export class UIRouterGlobals {
        params$:Observable<StateParams>;
    }
    export class UIRouter {
        globals: UIRouterGlobals
    }
}`

Answer (score -1):

You need to implements the `Resolver`. You can have a look here :

https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

The Resolve perform route data retrieval before route activation. So you can assign & manage your data before anything else happen.

This is mine resolver when certain actions are called :

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<something> {
        return this.myService.getTitle(route.params[something.property])
            .do(result => {
                if (result && !!Object.keys(result).length) {
                    //action to update what you want
                } else {
                    this.notificationsService.addNotification(<Notification>{
                        text: this.localizationKeys.deletedOrNotExisting,
                        type: MessageColorType.warning
                    });
                    this.router.navigate([...])]); 
                    // tell the router where to go if there is any error
                }
            });

    }
```

You can Inject a service in your component that keeps track about every change and use it to get access to your child parameter. As the resolver's logic is called even if you don't do a refresh, you can add few line of code to 'save' your current state.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to answer, but I'm not using angular router. I'm using [UI-Router](https://ui-router.github.io/).

Comment: Ui-Router have resolve too! Just check it there -> https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki and search for "Resolve" with a `ctrl+f`, it is explained very well and it's the same logic has my answer up above.

Comment: I already use resolve, see my code snippet in my question. Do you mean to say I can get child parameter value from resolve? How?

Comment: You can Inject a service in your component that keeps track about every change and use it to get access to your child parameter. As the resolver's logic is called even if you don't do a refresh, you can add few line of code to 'save' your current state.

Comment: That might work, although I think a bit hacky. I'll do it if there is no other options. Thanks!